# Three.js THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry multiple sampler2D vertical tearings

Tags: three.js, webgl, fragment-shader

I have created a RawShaderMaterial for an InstancedBufferGeometry object that is rendering well with 1 sampler2D uniform. As soon as it uses a second sampler2D uniform, it renders with a lot of vertical tearings

[image: see pix]
Here is the fragment shader:

```
precision highp float;

uniform sampler2D utexture1;
uniform sampler2D utexture2;

varying float vindex;
varying vec2 vUv;
varying vec3 mapcolor;
vec4 gettexture(){
    vec4 color;
    if(vindex==0.){
        color = texture2D(utexture1, vUv)*vec4(mapcolor,1.);
    }else if(vindex==1.){
        color = texture2D(utexture1, vUv)*vec4(mapcolor,1.);
    }else if(vindex==2.){
        color = texture2D(utexture2, vUv)*vec4(mapcolor,1.);
    }else if(vindex==3.){
        color = texture2D(utexture2, vUv)*vec4(mapcolor,1.);
    }
    return color;
}
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = gettexture();
}
```

Notes: The 2 textures used for the sampler2D have the same size (512x512) and they are loaded before material creation.

Anyone knows where these vertical tearings come from?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: A guess is `vindex` is not always an integer, so `color` is not always assigned a value. Intitialze `color` to `vec4( 1., 0., 0., 1. )` to test.

Comment: @WestLangley, thx for the info, unfortunatly, the temp color initialisation is doing the same behavior. As a matter of fact if I remove the condition and hard code it to the second sampler2D, it behaves the same way. I have tried to use a sampler2D array and it is the same, the first sampler is fine and the rest is tearing away. The result is animated for 10-13 sec (if the camera don't move), then it freezes to something like in the picture.

Comment: Ok, @WestLangley, your intuition was right, it is in deed an initialisation issue... I have found out from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25868381/webgl-stripes-when-using-multiple-textures, the int index needs to be rounded up before casting, i.e.: int i = int(vindex + 0.5); Let it behold, it is now working as expected! thank you for the fast replies++